# OneDrive UNC paths

Tags: onedrive

This is not supported but does anyone know how to force OneDrive for Business use UNC paths?

I've spoke with MS and its not on their roadmap and they arent forth coming with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we rank the feature request among the community, post your feature in user voice and MS will identify the priority of the feature based on the voting numbers.

Here is the user voice for office 365 website:
https://office365.uservoice.com/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is supported. Same format as it is for SharePoint Online document library mappings. \tenant-my.sharepoint.com\personal\username\Documents
Connect as Web Drive: https://tenant-my.sharepoint.com/personal/username/Documents

The option is only hidden in the OneDrive simplified UI. You can even turn it on by adding a normal view to the Documents library and turning the ribbon on from Settings (note that of course open in Explorer only shows in IE).

[Open in Explorer from OneDrive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B69IP.png)