# Save files to OneDrive using Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Our systems are changing over to cloud storage so our personal drives will be vanishing soon, therefore I need to save applications to users OneDrives.

This is new territory for me and what I am reading online is not making much sense.

**This is what I have so far:**

```
Set FileSystemObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim FileExistsbol As Boolean
Dim stFileName As String
Dim CopyFrom As String
Dim CopyTo As String

stFileName = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\OneDrive - Company"
stFileName = Trim(stFileName)
FileExistsbol = dir(stFileName) <> vbNullString

If FileExistsbol Then
 Kill stFileName
 CopyFrom = "C:\Test File.txt"
 CopyTo = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\OneDrive - Company"
 FileSystemObject.CopyFile CopyFrom, CopyTo
Else
 CopyFrom = "C:\Test File.txt"
 CopyTo = "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\OneDrive - Company"
 FileSystemObject.CopyFile CopyFrom, CopyTo
End If
```

This code has previously worked for copying to local drives, but believe it's not working on this occasion because the new drives it's trying to copy to is web based.

**Error:**
No error is actually being populated

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you could ***map*** the OneDrive folder so it behaves as a local drive.

Comment: Is that possible to do using VBA? There will be a lot o fusers having to do it manually otherwise

Comment: Should be possible, yes. The exact method would depend on your Windows version, etc, but probably the easiest way would be to figure out [with a Google search] how to map a drive letter to OneDrive via the command prompt, and then use `Shell` to execute the command if/when necessary.

Comment: I think your answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42840430/78522
Not need to map if you can get the UNC (which is an HTTPS address)

Answer (score 0):

Note that your variable `stFileName` contains the directory path not a filename, and so the `kill` expression is targeting the directory.

---

However, instead of testing for and deleting the file, how about using the `overwrite` argument for the `CopyFile` method, e.g.:

```
Dim objFSO As New FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objFSO.CopyFile "C:\Test File.txt", "C:\Users\" & Environ("UserName") & "\OneDrive - Company", True
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

You'll need to add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime in your project to enable the `objFSO` variable in my example to be defined using early binding.