# Saving files to Onedrive Folder in File Explorer

Tags: excel, vba, directory, save, onedrive

I'm trying to save a file to an Onedrive folder that syncs within file explorer. Do I need a network path for this to work properly? This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Macro4()
Dim myDir, strFilename, strPathname, strDateTime As String
strDateTime = " (" & Format(Now, "hhmm AM/PM") & ")"
myDir = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Folder 1\Folder2\Folder3\" & Worksheets("Private").Range("L5").Value
strFilename = Worksheets("HWR DATA - Craft").Range("C1").Value
strPathname = myDir & "\" & strFilename
MyMkDir myDir & "\"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPathname & strDateTime & ".xlsm", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

L5 refers to a cell that contains the following data:
*Folder A\Folder B\Folder C*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48183546/save-files-to-onedrive-using-access-vba

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?sxsrf=ACYBGNRNwI7jdiVc5-txu1BLjQg4c0BErg%3A1578370221320&source=hp&ei=rQQUXqjmEaeG4-EPppit8AU&q=excel+vba+save+to+onedrive&oq=vba+code+to+save+to+one&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i22i30.1545.4438..6800...1.0..0.260.2706.1j21j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0j0i131j35i39.wwqB3tzd4Yg

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The problem was with my code running into a problem with Microsoft's max length for the path to my folder. (256-character limit for creating links to other files).