# VBA how to "free up space" on OneDrive

Tags: vba, onedrive

Hello and thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide.

I have a macro that loops through files on my server and creates a backup copy on OneDrive.  I have chosen to do this through excel vba.  Excel is not installed on the server and I don't have enough Office 365 licenses to install it on that machine.  Instead, I have the macro running on a workstation.  This workstation does not have very much memory and will quickly fill up.

I have noticed that if I right click on the OneDrive folder in File Explorer, I can click on 'Free up space' and OneDrive "pushes" those folders off of my local drive and into the cloud to be used on demand.  I am hoping to do this from within the vba macro.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979146/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-onedrive-business-sharepoint-with-vba) helps you?

Also, remember you can save excel files as xlsb which will also save some space if you are backing up lots of data.

Comment: Thanks, This may be a workaround.  Instead of pushing the backup through my mapped folder this would allow me to push it directly to the cloud...  I will check it out...

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to make it work.  I don't have OneDrive for Business, just the personal version.  As it turns out, I was able to run the macro through the local OneDrive account and I still have the same amount of free space on the local drive despite backing up 30 GB of data to the cloud...

Comment: Hummm thats weird, and u deleted the files in the local drive?