# How do I integrate this VBA code into my companies onedrive/teams cloud database to save daily?

Tags: excel, vba

This code is intended to collect torque data off of a machine and create a file based off of the data it received on that day. Then, it saves it in the cloud so that it can be reviewed later if needed.

```
Public Sub UploadDataToFile()
   
    'Get today's date
    currentDate = Date
   
    'Get the last row of data in column B
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
   
    'Loop through each row in the data range
    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Cells(i, "B").Value < currentDate Then
            'If the date in column B is less than today's date, delete the entire row
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
   
    'Set the file name based on current date
    fileName = Format(currentDate, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "TorqueValues.xlsx"
   
    'Set the file path for saving in OneDrive for Business
    filePath = "C:\Austin Manufacturing Engineering\Documents\General\LVF Capper Torque\" & fileName
    
    
    'Copy the data to a new workbook
    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Add
   
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy newWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Cells
   
    'Save the new workbook at the specified file path with file format
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    newWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filePath, FileFormat:=51
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   
    newWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Right now, I have the major building blocks of the code, but I can't seem to figure out how to integrate in into our system with the correct file path. I keep getting errors when I run the code. I am getting Run time error 1004, it says the file path doesn't exist. The debugger highlights newWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=filePath, FileFormat:=51 as the error.

Comment: Possibly helpful similar question about saving to OneDrive: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56979146/how-do-i-upload-a-file-to-onedrive-business-sharepoint-with-vba